# How to change to directory when i click on link in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new in wordpress and sorry for my poor English.

I want to run the hello.php from input/index.php to input/output/hello.php when the link on index.php was clicked. I have googled it but cannot find the solution ? Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

At first if you are new in wordpress look how you can create theme and how it works(http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). Then please provide where you have created that directories. Also when you are working in wordpress you have to work only in themes folder and plugins folder you can simply implement it root dir where is you wp-config but I am sure it will not give you the result that you are trying to achieve.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

1. Log into WordPress
2. On the left hand menu click "Pages"
3. Create a page and title it "Hello"
4. Go into your FTP and into your theme folder: `wp-content/themes/your-theme`
5. Open `page.php` and copy it's code, paste it into a new file and call it `page-hello.php`
6. Upload `page-hello.php` now visit your page your just created.

According to WordPresses Template Hierarchy you can create a page based on the WordPress page slug, all you have to do is prepend `page-` before the slug.